# Edge Swipe Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

Can you recommend a JS library that actually **provides** edge swipe functionality when working with bare-bones HTML & CSS?

I've searched all over and haven't found a source of truth for that problem.
I've seen lots and lots of libraries enabling swipe gestures but not edge swipe.

My last attempt was using *Hammer.js* which I've tried implementing as:

```
var swipe = new Hammer(document);
// detect swipe and call to a function
swipe.on('swiperight swipeleft', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var endPoint = e.pointers[0].pageX;
    var distance = e.distance;
    var origin = endPoint - distance;

    //swipe right to open nav
    if (origin <= 15 && e.type == 'swiperight') {
        // open main menu
        $('#navigation-menu').animate({
            left: '0'
        });
    } else {
        // close/hide menu(s)
        $('#navigation-menu').animate({
            left: '-100%'
        });
    }
});
```

Further, if not using any library, **how can I implement a mobile edge swipe to show and hide content, (in my case it'd be a navigation menu)** with vanilla JS?

At this point I'm open to either solution/direction.

Comment: a very simple and stupid way is to create a dummy layer on top of the page. Lets say that your width is 400px create  a dummy layer on the left and right of 75 px and attach hammer.js to that element. you will get the edge swipe rightway. This is not a very good solution. But will help you achieve what you want. Let me see hammerjs

Comment: would you mind posting an answer with a fiddle example?

Comment: Requests for libraries are off-topic.

Comment: moreover I'm requesting/seeking a solution.

Comment: In that case, your question should reflect that, and also indicate what you've tried so far.

Comment: Did you see the link posted in my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162041/how-to-create-an-edge-swipe-with-hammer-js

Comment: @jhpratt: I think he has already tried something and posted another question Yesterday. Since it hasn't got much attention he has raised another question

Comment: @NullisTrue Just because you don't receive an answer doesn't mean you re-ask the question the following day. That's what bounties are for after you've waited the required 2 days.

Comment: @jhpratt this is becoming about something else. Also I'm asking the question seeking a solution that can be with or without hammer.js which was the topic of my first question. So in essence the questions are not the same. A simple point and direction would help me. But you also saying that libraries are off topic. So what's the protocol here?

Comment: Stack Overflow is _not_ a forum. The questions are nearly identical. If I hadn't already flagged this, I would flag it as a duplicate of your question yesterday. If you're trying to do it in vanilla JS, _what have you tried_?

Comment: I tried using hammer, couldn't get it to work. I don't know how to implement in vanilla JS (reason for title above).... Seeking guidance here. We're discussing semantics. We're not in accordance because I asked a question involving hammer.js, now I broaden it for JS in general including other libraries. all I'm asking is for a direction.

Comment: ...which is still off topic. You're expected to have a _specific_ problem. Without that, we can't help you.

Comment: Can you post the specific code you tried with hammer.js that isn't working? I'm assuming you lowered the threshold within the Hammer object,etc, correct? I've had to rewrite Hammer functionality before and I've had success, but in this case obviously a web page can only track what happens within the confines of the window. The only thing I can think of is to track the mouseover/press coordinates at the outer edge of the document and track the speed that the cursor travels over pixels to determine whether or not an event should be fired. Ironically that should be exactly what Hammer is for.

Comment: @zfrisch I just updated the question with how far I've got using hammer. thanks!

Comment: @zfrisch please let me know, if that is somewhat in the direction that you're suggesting above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution, you can set thresholdStart, End, Milliseconds. You may want to tidy up the code, and port it for touch events (I used mouse events for testing in my browser more easily).

Use:
swipeEdgeFromLeft function and swipeEdgeFromRight function.

```js
var div = document.body;
var mouse = {
  isDown: false,
  inLeft: false,
  inRight: false,
  downTimestamp: null
};
var width, thresholdStart, thresholdEnd, thresholdMilliseconds;

function resize(){
  width = window.innerWidth;
  thresholdStart = 0.1*width;//within 10% of screen width
  thresholdEnd = 0.13*width;//beyond 13% of screen width
  thresholdMilliseconds = 500;//must be done in 500 milliseconds
}
document.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);
resize();//initialize

div.addEventListener('mousedown'/*'touchstart'*/, function(e){
 var x = e./*touches[0].*/pageX;
 mouse.isDown = true;
 mouse.downTimestamp = performance.now();

 if(x < thresholdStart){
  mouse.inLeft = true;
 } else if(x > width-thresholdStart){
  mouse.inRight = true;
 }
});
div.addEventListener('mousemove'/*'touchmove'*/, function(e){
 
  var x = e./*touches[0].*/pageX;
  if(mouse.inLeft && x > thresholdEnd){
    mouse.inLeft = false;
    if(performance.now() - mouse.downTimestamp < thresholdMilliseconds){
      swipeEdgeFromLeft();
    }
  } else if(mouse.inRight && x < width-thresholdEnd){
    mouse.inRight = false;
    if(performance.now() - mouse.downTimestamp < thresholdMilliseconds){
      swipeEdgeFromRight();
    }
  }
});
div.addEventListener('mouseup'/*'touchend'*/, function(e){
 //var x = e./*changedTouches[0].*/pageX;
 mouse.isDown = false;
 mouse.inLeft = false;
 mouse.inRight = false;
 mouse.downTimestamp = null;
});
function swipeEdgeFromLeft(){
 console.log("edge swipe from left");
}
function swipeEdgeFromRight(){
 console.log("edge swipe from right");
}
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.bar {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#left-inner-threshold {
  width: calc(0.1 * 100vw);
  left: 0;
}
#right-inner-threshold {
  width: calc(0.1 * 100vw);
  right: 0;
}
#left-outer-threshold {
  width: calc(0.13 * 100vw);
  left: 0;
}
#right-outer-threshold {
  width: calc(0.13 * 100vw);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-inner-threshold" class="bar"></div>
<div id="left-outer-threshold" class="bar"></div>
<div id="right-inner-threshold" class="bar"></div>
<div id="right-outer-threshold" class="bar"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you George! I'll go through it and try to translate it to my use case.

Comment: the resize implementation would follow just like the one you wrote?

Comment: yes I just implemented resize. thresholdStart is the number of pixels from the left or right of the screen, at which the user can begin the swipe action. for example 0.25*width would be 25% of the width. thresholdEnd is similar, but is the point at which the swipe function is triggered, if they start within thresholdStart and move beyond thresholdEnd.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. apologies, I was just editing my comment before yours...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution to your existing code using Hammer.js v2.0.8

The explanation for how to achieve the edge swipe can be found [here](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1080) answered by @jovinbm.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    const swipe = new Hammer(document);
    function getStartPosition(e) {
        const delta_x = e.deltaX;
        const delta_y = e.deltaY;
        const final_x = e.srcEvent.pageX || e.srcEvent.screenX || 0;
        const final_y = e.srcEvent.pageY || e.srcEvent.screenY || 0;

        return {
            x: final_x - delta_x,
            y: final_y - delta_y
        }
    };

    swipe.on('swiperight swipeleft', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { x } = getStartPosition(e);
        console.log(x);
        //swipe right to open nav /* note the condition here */
        if (e.type == 'swiperight' && x >= 0 && x <= 50) {
            // open menu
            $('#navigation').animate({
                left: '0'
            });
            //swiping left should slide out nav and/or sub-nav
        } else {
            // close/hide menu
            $('#navigation, #task-menu').animate({
                left: '-100%'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/tonkihonks/pen/wmKMbz?editors=1111) showing it in action:

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! I chose George Campbell's answer but both of you guys got me out of this rabbit hole.

Comment: const final_x = e.center.x || e.srcEvent.pageX || e.srcEvent.screenX || 0;

Answer (score 2):

For swipes, only the final `pointerup` event is included as the `srcEvent` in the event object passed to your handler (see http://hammerjs.github.io/api/). The initial `pointerdown` event that carries the details of the initial position of where the swipe event started is not provided in the hammer event object. Fortunately, you can use the `srcEvent` in the event object  to get the starting position of the event initial `pointerdown` event.

```
const getStartPosition = (e) => {
  const delta_x = e.deltaX;
  const delta_y = e.deltaY;
  const final_x = e.srcEvent.pageX || e.srcEvent.screenX || 0;
  const final_y = e.srcEvent.pageY || e.srcEvent.screenY || 0;

  return {
    x: final_x - delta_x,
    y: final_y - delta_y
  };
};

const handleSwipe = (e) => {
  const {x} = getStartPosition(e);

  if (x >= 0 && x <= 50) {
    // handle swipe from left edge e.t.c
  }
  else {
    // handle other case
  }
};
```

The `srcEvent` is just a normal javascript event that inherits properties from [UIEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent) hence the `pageX/pageY` api above. This will probably not work in other browsers since some of them are [not standardized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/pageX)